# Image is not showing up when binding the Source in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

There are some explanations out there for a similar problem, but I still don't understand what I did wrong. I have an Image in `C:/Image.png`.

Now I started a WPF-Project in MVVM-Pattern, where I have a usercontrol for the image:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.DataContext>
        <vm:LSImageVM/>
    </Grid.DataContext>

    <Image x:Name="Picture" Source="{Binding LSImage, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}"/>
</Grid>
```

This is the Viewmodel-Class for the image:

```
public class LSImageVM : ViewModelBase
{
    private ImageSource _image;
    private LockscreenSettingsClass settings;


    public LSImageVM()
    {
        var json = File.ReadAllText("C:/Program Files/LSL/settings.json");
        settings = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LockscreenSettingsClass>(json);

        Uri imageUri = new Uri(settings.Path, UriKind.Relative);
        BitmapImage imageBitmap = new BitmapImage(imageUri);
        LSImage = imageBitmap;
    }

    public ImageSource LSImage
    {
        get => _image;

        set
        {
            _image = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

So I get my settings from a Json, which looks like this:

```
{
    "Path": "C:/Image.png",
    "Interval": 5000,
    "LogPath": "C:/Lockscreen.log"
}
```

Then the path described in the settings (`C:/Image.png` in this case) gets converted into a BitmapImage, that I use as the ImageSource I've bound in the xaml above.

At this point, when I build the project, I can see the image in my xaml-editor:

[image]

Now I add the Usercontrol to my MainWindow:

```
<Window x:Class="LockscreenSettings_MVVM.View.Windows.Main_Window"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:uc="clr-namespace:LockscreenSettings.View.UserControls"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LockscreenSettings_MVVM.View.Windows"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Main_Window" Height="500" Width="400" ResizeMode="NoResize">
    <Grid>
        <uc:LSImageUC/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And this is the point where I cannot see the image when I start the Program.

What did I miss out?

Comment: You can do the same with LSImage as a string and assigning the path of the image to it will do the work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`C:/Image.png` is not a relative URI, hence `UriKind.Relative` is wrong.

Try

```
LSImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(settings.Path, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
```

---

As a note, setting `NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True` on the `Image.Source` Binding seems pointless, since you don't use the Binding's `SourceUpdated` event.

This is sufficient:

```
<Image Source="{Binding LSImage}"/>
```

Comment: That did it. Thanks. Didn't focus on that, as the image was visible in the editor

Answer (score 0):

Set the `[assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguage("en")]` to `en` culture in `AssemblyInfo.cs` file.

```
[assembly: AssemblyTrademark("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCulture("")]
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguage("en")]
```